Watching TV causes man to turn to stone
I remember some movie back in the 80s, which started off with some elderly man who was watching TV at night who slowly became petrified due to his body turning to stone. HIs wife finds him and screams when he starts crumbling before her.
Sometime later in the movie, it is revealed that the stone-like nature of the petrification was not stone, but calcium. People who had turned to stone were watching a screen at the time, and being subliminally programmed to have their bodies pump calcium from their bones into their bloodstream causing the petrification.
Some time later there is a possible threat that the US president (who for some reason I thought may be played by Martin Sheen, although I can't seem to find anything in IMDb relating to a possible portrayal of a US President, except for The West Wing) may be assassinated in this way... The assassination is eventually thwarted... 
As far as I know, this movie has only appeared on TV... Anyone know what movie I may be referring to?

It sounds like the TV movie Fatal Error, (1999), which features a computer virus that can cross over and infect humans through video watching. Were you thinking of Robert Wagner instead of Martin Sheen? The trailer is on Zimbio.

This sounds like it, and the effects that I saw are seriously jogging my memory... I believe this is it...
